# AngularJS injecting one module in another module and call function

Tags: angularjs

code taken from here http://plnkr.co/edit/jcOwg8HgBGPtod4yCR5j?p=info

i read the below code but still i have confusion that how **notifytwo**'s instance is getting pass to factory notify ?

factory notify has function called **sampleFun** which call function **sampleFunTwo** of another factory called **notifytwo** but i have not found when and how **notifytwo**'s instance is getting pass to factory **notify** ?

please help me to understand the code flow. thanks

```
var myModule= angular.module('MyServiceModuleOne', ['MyServiceModuleTwo']);
myModule.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'notify', function($scope, notify){
        $scope.getFn = function() {
          notify.sampleFun();
        }
      }]);

    myModule.factory('notify', 
        function(notifytwo) {
        return {

         sampleFun: function() {
                      notifytwo.sampleFunTwo();

                      },      
              };
        }
    );



    var myModuleTwo= angular.module('MyServiceModuleTwo',[]);
    myModule.factory('notifytwo', 
        function() {
        return {

         sampleFunTwo: function() {
                   alert('From notify two');
                  }    
          };
        }
    );
```

Comment: It's called 'dependency injection'. Angular looks up which dependency was called 'notifytwo', and injects that factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notify factory is able to call the factory notifyTwo because notifyTwo is being injected when creating the instance of notify:

```
myModule.factory('notify', 
    function(notifytwo) //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE IT'S INJECTED
```

Comment: notify instance has been created in controller function `getFn()` so there `MyServiceModuleTwo` was injected in module and it is enough to call ?

Comment: That's not the order in which it actually happens: the dependencies were registered in angulars `$injector` service when `MyServiceModuleOne` got bootstrapped. The module is dependant on `MyServiceModuleTwo`, so that gets fired up first. Then the `TestController` gets registered, which in turn is dependant on the factory `notify`. Thus `notify` is created (or the instance of `notify` is fetched, if it already got created somewhere else) even before the controller can be registered. Finally the `notify`-instance gets passed to the controller and thus can be used at runtime.